# Python shutil.copytree performance issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shutil

I am trying to copy files and folders with `shutil.copytree()`. The structure is as follows:

- mainfolder

  - subfolder

    - 7.000 pdf files
  - 1 inp file

Is `shutil.copytree()` the right approach? Because it takes like forever to copy the 7k pdf files. At the end I need a copy of main folder and all it's content in an archive folder. The original I am moving via `shutil.move()` to an upload folder.

I am really struggeling here and need an efficient way to create a duplicate.

Comment: could you define "forever"?  is it slower or faster than doing the same using, e.g., the command line or GUI?  also what OS are you doing this under, using MS Windows with a virus checker enabled could indeed cause this to take minutes.

Comment: On average it copies three files per minute (with an average size of 350 kb). It ist faster than the GUI and command line. I am using Windows10 with a virus checker enabled.
The script is to supposed to run on an windows server, if it works properly. My task was to "translate" an old batch file into python. Executing the batch file, the subprocess of copying all the files was a matter of seconds.

Comment: do you have any control over the virus checker?  e.g. can you switch to a better one (taking 20 seconds to check a single file seems terrible) or just disable it for these directories?  I'd expect it to be able to copy that many files in less than a couple of minutes (and much less with a fast SSD, ~4 seconds on my Linux box)

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any control over the checker.